# How do I modify a JSON Object in a JSON list?

Tags: c#, json

My JSON list looks like this,(Where Type 3 is the CommandType.Welcome):

```
[
  {
    "Keyword": "Hello",
    "Type": 0,
    "Message": "World"
  },
  {
    "Keyword": "Hi",
    "Type": 0,
    "Message": "There"
  },
  {
    "Keyword": "Test",
    "Type": 0,
    "Message": "test"
  },
  {
    "Keyword": "Greeting",
    "Type": 3,
    "Message": "Welcome"
  }
]
```

My current method will pull the correct Object from the list and modify the object but it isn't modify the List Object. For Example, command.message = message but when I serialize the list it doesn't merge the changes.

```
    public void SetGreetMessage(string message)
    {
        var leaveGreet = new LeaveGreetService();
        foreach (var command in leaveGreet.CommandList.Where(x => x.Type == CommandType.Welcome))
        {
            command.Message = message;
            dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CommandList, Formatting.Indented);

            File.WriteAllText("Commands.txt", jsonData);
        }
    }
```

I have looked online at a few resources and most parse into a string and modify it with the string. But I was wondering if it was possible to do it like this somehow. I know I can add a new object to it with this method but modifying seems to be a great feat.

Edit:

```
using System;

namespace vVvBot.Model
{
    public class CustomCommand
    {
        public string Keyword { get; set; }
        public CommandType Type { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public enum CommandType
    {
        Message,
        Faq,
        Action,
        Welcome,
        Leaving
    }
}
```

CommandList is the list of the command Object from the file

Comment: shouldn't the last two lines be outside the loop?

Comment: What's the type of CommandList? is it the collection command objects, Is command a C# class?

Comment: @HaseebAsif I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you're passing command parameter incorrectly and json isn't being generated. I have changed `serializeObject` parameter from `CommandList` to `command`.

```
public void SetGreetMessage(string message)
    {
        var leaveGreet = new LeaveGreetService();
        foreach (var command in leaveGreet.CommandList.Where(x => x.Type == CommandType.Welcome))
        {
            command.Message = message;
            dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command, Formatting.Indented);

            File.WriteAllText("Commands.txt", jsonData);
        }
    }
```